# ecommerce using stripes

Tags: dynamic, e-commerce, dispatcher, stripes

We have planned to start an e commerce project using Stripes + Hibernate.

Please let me know if it is good to have admin & user part in same project or two separate ones.
If it is a single project , how do i separate admin side code & user code.

for eg: if i have admin actions in com.ecommerce.adminactions pacakge and user actions in com.ecommerce.useractions package should i use dynamicmappingfilter to direct admin request to com.ecommerce.adminactions and user request to com.ecommerce.useractions ?

-http://myecommerce.com/admin/* - > should always go to com.ecommerce.adminactions

-http://myecommerce.com/ -> should go to com.ecommerce.useractions

or
Should i use @urlbinding(/admin/st.action) in each class (Hard code).

The requirement is they need multistore concept.
Please let me know your thoughts on this.Your thoughts & suggestions will be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [Stripes framework](http://www.stripesframework.org/) does not really influence decisions on how you should organize you're project, or how you should organize your IDE project structure, or even Java package structure or URL structure.

**One or more project**

Unless you have many developers, keep it all in a single project.

**Package structure**

A package structure should organize you're Java classes so that you put classes that are logically related (as defined by your architecture!) is in the same package. For example: *com.ecommerce.action.admin* and *com.ecommerce.action.*. See also: [Properly package your Java classes](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1049863.html)

**URL structure**

Typically you want you're URL structure to reflect the logical structure of your website (not the same as your technical structure). To accomplish this, you should not rely on the default URL's but use [@UrlBinding](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/action/UrlBinding.html). With the annotation you do not hard code links, as all generated links will automatically use the UrlBinding pattern.

**Multi store concept**

For a multi store concept, you will need to build logic in your application for distinguishing between the different shops. For example by adding a *shop id* to your URL parameters. Or more sophisticated by detecting the (sub)domain name used and map that to a *shop id* (You can implement this by using an interceptor).

Comment: Thanks much Kdeveloper. I will use @UrlBinding for admin. About multi store concept our requirement is not to pass the store id in url but store name(keywords like men,women) suppose store url is **shop.com** if they create a new exclusive store for men then url will be **men.shop.com**. we need to get this keyword "men" in our class and identify its store id. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.